# Plot boxplot with area chart in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to plot boxplot with area chart but I don't know how to add area chart after I plot boxplot.

here the data i used :

```
structure(list(x = structure(c(18314L, 18314L, 18314L, 18314L, 
18314L, 18314L, 18314L, 18314L, 18314L, 18314L, 18314L, 18314L, 
18314L, 18314L, 18314L, 18314L, 18314L, 18314L, 18314L, 18314L, 
18314L, 18314L, 18314L, 18315L, 18315L, 18315L, 18315L, 18315L, 
18315L, 18315L, 18315L, 18315L, 18315L, 18315L, 18315L, 18315L, 
18315L, 18315L, 18315L, 18315L, 18315L, 18315L, 18315L, 18315L, 
18315L, 18315L, 18315L, 18316L, 18316L, 18316L, 18316L, 18316L, 
18316L, 18316L, 18316L, 18316L, 18316L, 18316L, 18316L, 18316L, 
18316L, 18316L, 18316L, 18316L, 18316L, 18316L, 18316L, 18316L, 
18316L, 18316L, 18316L), class = "Date"), y = c(24.2471666666667, 
22.0866666666667, 23.25525, 22.90175, 21.3551666666667, 22.639, 
22.5633333333333, 21.5476666666667, 22.4529166666667, 21.1831666666667, 
21.065, 20.8060833333333, 19.3153333333333, 20.4245833333333, 
20.2316666666667, 18.9655833333333, 20.49575, 19.7771666666667, 
17.6696666666667, 18.76425, 17.9373333333333, 15.7266666666667, 
16.4498333333333, 16.5565, 14.72075, 15.7441666666667, 16.0895, 
15.2769166666667, 16.0465833333333, 15.5703333333333, 15.1585, 
15.193, 14.7855, 15.2318333333333, 14.891, 13.8044166666667, 
14.8228333333333, 14.0265, 13.3326666666667, 14.6345833333333, 
13.9368333333333, 13.25425, 14.57225, 13.8561666666667, 12.739, 
14.4376666666667, 12.5178333333333, 10.4075833333333, 11.7431666666667, 
9.26116666666667, 7.66263636363636, 10.285, 8.23918181818182, 
6.272, 7.88, 7.2076, 5.948875, 5.33, 7.01281818181818, 4.97408333333333, 
6.114, 8.78925, 8.71483333333333, 9.90091666666667, 12.2376666666667, 
13.7695, 14.4801666666667, 16.6445, 19.7036666666667, 19.5710833333333, 
20.68325)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -71L))
```

i tried:

```
box_plot <- ggplot(dataku, aes(x=x,y=y, group = x)) 
box_plot +
  geom_boxplot()
```

after I plot boxplot i tried to add area chart with :

```
box_plot +
  geom_boxplot() +
  geom_area(dataku, mapping = aes(x,y,fill=x))
```

the plot that i want to save:

[image]

Comment: could you add an example as `dput`?

Comment: i just add an exmpale as dput

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the area chart reflects the min and max values ... Try this. Basic idea is to use geom_ribbon and stat_summary to compute min and max values:

```r
library(ggplot2)

dataku$x <- as.Date(dataku$x)

ggplot(dataku) +
  stat_summary(aes(x, y), fun.min = min, fun.max = max, geom = "ribbon", fill = "orange", alpha = .6) +
  geom_boxplot(aes(x, y, fill = factor(x), group = x), alpha = .4)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-03-30 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: i run it and i got `Warning: Ignoring unknown parameters: fun.min, fun.max
No summary function supplied, defaulting to mean_se()`

Comment: What version of ggplot2 have you installed? I'm using the recently updated v3.3.0.

Comment: ... or simply reinstall via install.packages("ggplot2").